# Adding section to appsettings.json causes crash

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm building a Asp.Net MVC (.Net Core 2.0) application on OS X.

The modified the `appsettings.json` to be:

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    Interval":  15
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

The build succeeds, but execution halts at the `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` line in the `Program.cs` file:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
}
```

Did I miss something?

Reference: [AppSettings in ASP.NET Core](http://thomasardal.com/appsettings-in-asp-net-core/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like your appsettings is valid JSON. You're missing a double quote around Interval. Try

```
 {
  "AppSettings": {
    "Interval":  15
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sooo... it's a typo then?

Comment: Yes, it appears to be a typo.

Comment: We have a specific close reason for questions that are simple typos :)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I wasn't aware :)

Comment: No worries, but next time think about voting to close rather than answering.

Comment: Absolutely, I will!

Comment: "No worries, but next time think about voting to close rather than answering."  No reason to be helpful then either.

Comment: @craig I never suggested the reason cannot be given in a comment, that's what I would do. However, SO is a repository of questions for future people, not just you, and this question doesn't help anyone.

Comment: @DavidG, I disagree.  If the IDE would have indicated that there was an issue with the syntax or had raised an error (rather than crashing), then I would have easily identified the error and not posted the question.  Until the IDE has full syntax checking, then this question *could* be helpful to others.  It was certainly helpful to me.

Comment: @craig You assume the IDE doesn't already tell you... https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUrlF.png

Comment: @DavidG the OS X version (7.1.1) doesn't have the same UI, so I didn't notice the unobtrusive error (https://imgur.com/a/6xZeZ).  My mistake.

Answer (score -1):

Simply you can follow this format.

```
  {
    "Logging": {
       "IncludeScopes": false,
       "LogLevel": {
       "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "Config1": {
      "Key": "value"
   },

 "Config2": {
     "Key1": "value1",
     "key1": "value2"
 }
```